# Why is my Node.js website not finding pages in public folder?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

I am quite new to web development with `node.js`. I have an issue where loading one of my pages is giving the following error in my browser:

```
Cannot GET /public/pages/terms-and-conditions.html
```

The file structure looks like the following:

- index.html
- index.js
- public/

  - pages/

    - terms-and-conditions.html

My index.js file looks like:

```
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path')
const app = new express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile('./index.html',{ root: __dirname });
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port 3000!`));
```

My button that directs them to `terms-and-conditions` is located in the `index.html` file and does the following:

```
<li><a href="/public/pages/terms-and-conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
```

I have tried a many different paths to my file but must be missing something obvious.

### SOLVED:

I needed to keep the path like follows:

```
<li><a href="pages/terms-and-conditions.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "/public/pages/terms-and-conditions.html" is indicating that this is an absolute path.

Try "./public/pages/terms-and-conditions.html".

Comment: Hi thank you for you answer - I have tried this just now and still the same error.

Comment: Ok than remove the slash altogether so you have "public/pages/terms-and-conditions.html"

Comment: I still get the same error, I have cleared cache and made sure I am restarting properly. the URL also shows '...localhost:3000/public/pages/terms-and-conditions.html' which seems to be correct

Comment: I have solved the issue, I needed to keep the path: pages/terms-and-conditions.html without the 'public' ... I will update my question to show the answr